# Память в стеке под отдельный поток?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, стек

можно ли в c# да и вообще выделить память в стеке под отдельный поток - больше или меньше 1 мб?
просто мне сказали что нельзя выделять ни больше (ну это ладно), но и не меньше.
Говорят, что процессора есть пять режимов работы(я не вдавался в подробности) - и под каким то из этих режимов на какой-то там архитектуре(пустое для меня слово - все равно в этом не понимаю) все таки можно выделить памяти больше/меньше чем 1 мб. так ли это?
в видео курсе который я прохожу, автор зашел внутрь класса Thread что бы продемонстрировать, что у данного класса имеется 4 конструктора, где обратил внимание на этот :

```
public Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart start, int maxStackSize);
```

в котором вторым параметром указывается размер стека выделяемого под поток. Но при этом сказал, что мы не можем указать ни больше не меньше мегабайта - т.к " .... такова структура(не в буквальном смысле struct - а в переносном) адресации памяти в защищенном режиме работы процессора " - я так понимаю, что этот "защищенный режим " это стандартный режим работы процессора?!

Но при этом сказал, что мы не можем указать ни больше не меньше мегабайта - т.к " .... такова структура(не в буквальном смысле struct - а в переносном) адресации памяти в защищенном режиме работы процессора " - вот откуда возник поставленный в данной теме вопрос.

Comment: Терминологический момент: это не память в стеке выделяется под поток, это для потока при его старте выделяется (его собственный) стек определённого размера.

Comment: в шарпе (то есть в винде) - не знаю, но в линуксе легко поменять с помощью ulimit в любую сторону. Подозреваю, что в винде тоже. Тут пишут - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5cykbwz4(v=vs.110).aspx - что можно менять, но не всем и не всегда.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Не читайте советских газет до обеда.

1. Размер стэка по умолчанию для 32-битного кода равняется 1 Мб, для
   64-битного -- 4 Мб.
2. С помощью упомянутого вами конструктора размер стэка можно задавать любым, но с некоторыми ограничениями:

   - размер меньше минимального (256 Кб) не будет принят во внимание и стэку будет выделено минимальное количество памяти
   - должен существовать непрерывный блок свободной памяти указанного размера
   - размер стэка округляется по размеру страницы (обычно 64 Кб)
   - код должен работать в full trust, если вы хотите задать размер больше дефолтного
3. Если вы не вдаетесь в режимы работы процессора и архитектура процессора для вас пустое слово, вышеозвученная информация вам совершенно не нужна ([впрочем, как и большинству из тех, кто понимает](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070301-00/?p=27803)).

---

[Иллюстрация](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902956/1985167):

```
class Program
{
    private struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
    {
        public uint BaseAddress;
        public uint AllocationBase;
        public uint AllocationProtect;
        public uint RegionSize;
        public uint State;
        public uint Protect;
        public uint Type;
    }

    private const uint STACK_RESERVED_SPACE = 4096 * 16;
    private const int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int VirtualQuery(
        IntPtr lpAddress,
        ref MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer,
        int dwLength);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread");
        Console.WriteLine(EstimatedRemainingStackSizeInMegabytes());

        Console.WriteLine("New thread");
        var thread = new Thread(
            () => Console.WriteLine(EstimatedRemainingStackSizeInMegabytes()),
            16 * MEGABYTE);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private unsafe static float EstimatedRemainingStackSizeInMegabytes()
    {
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION stackInfo = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();
        IntPtr currentAddr = new IntPtr((uint)&stackInfo - 4096);

        VirtualQuery(currentAddr, ref stackInfo, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
        return (float)(currentAddr.ToInt64() - stackInfo.AllocationBase - STACK_RESERVED_SPACE) / MEGABYTE;
    }
}
```

Результат:

> Main thread
>
> 0.9277534
>
> New thread
>
> 15.93015

Comment: Так же советую добавить в ответ информацию по параметру `disableStackOverflowProbing` и возможных костылях при использовании этого конструктора для полноты картины.